# Deploying static file to Azure App Service using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-cli, azure-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a single file to an Azure App Service website using the Azure cli command as below:

```
    az webapp deploy --resource-group <group-name> --name <app-name> --src-path config.json --type=static
```

But when I run it I get an error stating:

```
    ERROR: An error occured during deployment. Status Code: 400, Details: "Path must be defined for type='Static'"
```

So then I define a path and get:

```
    ERROR: unrecognized arguments: --path=/home/site/wwwroot/xxx.json
```

I'm assuming this is because my website is not static.    I just want to deploy a single file from a known location in DevOps to the root directory on the website.

Any ideas how to solve this? thank you.

Comment: Your understanding of static is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

Initially I tried same commands to deploy a single file to an Azure App Service and got similar error.

**Commands:**

```
   az webapp deploy --resource-group <group-name> --name <app-name> --src-path config.json --type=static
```

**Console:**

[image]

According to this **[Ms-Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-deploy)** we need to deploy a file with **`source path`** and `target path`.

**Commands:**

```
az webapp deploy --resource-group ResouceGroup --name AppName --src-path SourcePath --type static --target-path staticfiles/test.txt
```

I tried the above command which can deploy a file to azure app service.

**Console:**

[image]

**Portal:**

You can check the deployments in the portal by
App-service -> advanced tools -> go -> Debug console ->path which you have stored.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Venkatesan, I was using the [Ms-Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli)  which doesn't mention 'target path' but just the snippet I showed you.  I will try adding the target path.

Answer (score 0):

Venkatesan's answer is correct.

Your understanding of 'Static' is not correct.

See this official document:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Azure-Web-App:-Configuration-Details#resource

So no need type.

On my side I just run two commands:

`@{} | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "xxx.json"`

`az webapp deploy --resource-group xxx --name xxx --src-path xxx.json --target-path site/wwwroot/xxx.json`

It works:

[image]

If you only need to change one time and your app service, directly move the file with mouse is a possible way.

You can also use [FTP method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp?tabs=portal) for automatic changing.

Comment: thank you very much - I will try without 'Static' too

Comment: Worked perfectly without static, thanks @Bowman Zhu-MSFT